# Limit by definition of a general case $\frac{1}{x^p}$

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification

Prove:
$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x^p} = 0 ~~~ \forall p \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0 \}$$

My solution:

Recall the definition, $ \forall \varepsilon > 0 $ There is $N > 0 $ (doesn't have to be an integer) such that if $x > N$ then $ \left | \frac{1}{x^p} - 0 \right | < \varepsilon $

Then, because $ \frac{1}{x^p}$ can be negative, for odd $p$'s, I thought to "decompose" $N$ to two parts. I will choose $N=1$ and then it is trivial that $ \frac{1}{x^p} > 0$ for all $x>1$ whether $p$ is odd or not.. and so $ | \frac{1}{x^p} - 0 | = \frac{1}{x^p}  < \varepsilon \\ \implies x > \frac{1}{\varepsilon^{\frac{1}{p}}}$

Thus we can choose:
$$ N = \max \{ 1, \frac{1}{\varepsilon^{\frac{1}{p}}} \}$$

I have a small question though -  if $ \varepsilon > 0$ than of course $\frac{1}{\varepsilon^{\frac{1}{p}}} > 0$ thus we can actually take $ N = \frac{1}{\varepsilon^{\frac{1}{p}}} + 1  > 1$ and thus delete the $\max$ part and only use one value for $N$. Is it correct so far? is it a valid solution?  Thank you!

Edit: I know $\varepsilon > 0 $ and thus if $\frac{1}{x^p}$ is negative than it is smaller than epsilon, of-course.. but how do I write this in a proof? in words? Thank you

Comment: Seems more correct to say, that as $N =\left\lfloor \frac{1}{\varepsilon^{\frac{1}{p}}} + 1 \right\rfloor +1  \gt \max \{ 1, \frac{1}{\varepsilon^{\frac{1}{p}}} \}$, then  we can use only value for $N$. For second note, that we have modulus in inequality.

Comment: $|\frac 1{x^{p}}|=\frac 1 {|x|^{p}}$. Do not split the proof into two cases. Just work with $|x|$.